# How do I delete a specific label on a frame that doesn't seem to have a name?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

currently I'm trying to create a button that deletes the labels another function produces. This other function creates labels all with the same name, like so:

```py
def display():
          global overall_data
          length = len(overall_data)
          print(length)
          for i in range(len(overall_data)):
             print("i = " + str(i))
             bg_colour = "Black"
             l = tk.Message(my_frame3, 
                          text = "Name = " + str(overall_data[i][0]) + "\n"
                                 "Health =           /" + str(overall_data[i][1]) + "   \n"
                                 "Armour Class = " + str(overall_data[i][2]) + "\n"
                                 "Initiative = " + str(overall_data[i][3]),
                          fg='White', 
                          bg=bg_colour)
             l.place(x = 20 + i*150, y = 60, width=120, height= 80)
             string = str(overall_data[i][1])
             data = tk.StringVar(my_frame3, value = string)
             health_input = tk.Entry(my_frame3, textvariable = data, width = 15,fg = "Black",bg = "White")
             health_input.place(x = 85 + i*150, y = 85, width = 25, height=15)
```

Basically, overall_data is a 2d array. This function will output each part of the array one at a time, e.g [[1,2,3,4], [2,3,4,5]],it would output  one label for [1,2,3,4] and another for [2,3,4,5].
Now I have another function that should remove all the labels produced by this function. Currently I tried just using:

```py
def remove_labels():
   my_frame3.destroy()
```

but this deletes the entire frame, which is self explanatory but I thought I might as well give it a shot. Another thing I tried is l.destroy(), but it also didn't work saying that l has not been defined which I think is because its a temporary variable existing just inside the for loop. I made l global, but then only the latest label for l would be destroyed. I've seen some answers suggesting pack, but I've been avoiding it in my code since I found place easier. Although if they are no other options I'll use it.

Comment: Simply use a list to store the labels, then you can go through the list to destroy them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got help in the comments, but posting here so it's easier to see. Basically just save the labels in a list as they are created and destroy them one by one later. Like this:

```py
        def display():
          global x   
          x = []
          global y
          y = []
          global overall_data
          length = len(overall_data)
          print(length)
          for i in range(len(overall_data)):
             print("i = " + str(i))
             global l
             bg_colour = "Black"
             l = tk.Message(my_frame3, 
                          text = "Name = " + str(overall_data[i][0]) + "\n"
                                 "Health =           /" + str(overall_data[i][1]) + "   \n"
                                 "Armour Class = " + str(overall_data[i][2]) + "\n"
                                 "Initiative = " + str(overall_data[i][3]),
                          fg='White', 
                          bg=bg_colour)
             x.append(l)
             l.place(x = 20 + i*150, y = 60, width=120, height= 80)
             string = str(overall_data[i][1])
             data = tk.StringVar(my_frame3, value = string)
             health_input = tk.Entry(my_frame3, textvariable = data, width = 15,fg = "Black",bg = "White")
             health_input.place(x = 85 + i*150, y = 85, width = 25, height=15)
             y.append(health_input)
        def remove_labels():
             for i in range(len(x)):
                  x[i].destroy()
             for i in range(len(y)):
                  y[i].destroy()
```

Answer (score 0):

If `my_frame3` contains only the widgets you want to destroy later, then you can modify `remove_labels()` as below:

```py
def remove_labels():
    for child in my_frame3.winfo_children():
        child.destroy()
```